# Extending custom fields in SCIM schema

Tags: azure, scim2

I'm currently working on SCIM users provisioning and I have a problem with extending custom fields. I was following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes

I've created 2 new attributes that will refer to CompanyName and UserId in convention:
urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:MyAppName:2.0:User:company
urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:MyAppName:2.0:User:userId

Next, I mapped them in Attributes Mapping:
[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30TIh.png)

I've run provisioning on demand for example user, in export section those field are filled with values: [Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7crdf.png) ,but in the json of a user those values are missing as well as schema definition in schemas section: [schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odkWU.png)

Am I missing any step? Maybe schema declaration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a known thing that AAD Provisioning won't include custom schema values in the schemas attribute. Your attribute names look to be in compliance with the SCIM spec. I think the issue may be in your code - there isn't a ton of information to work with here, but I'd check to see what the actual web request is before any processing happens to it and if the lack of the value in the schemas attribute is causing your code to strip those attributes from the JSON.

Beyond that, I'd suggest opening a support ticket with Azure AD.